# Is there a way to go within the tag of an svg tag?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have the following object returning me these tags with a `this` call.

[image: my image]

However, I'm trying to access the properties of the `<rect>` tag. Knowing that jQuery can't transverse svg tags, is there a way for me to call the inner rect tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
console.dir(document.querySelector('svg').firstElementChild);
```

You can navigate through the svg tag subtree using regular dom node methods

Comment: Thanks, the method I was looking for was .firstElementChild. Do all DOM node methods work on SVGElements? I thought SVG DOM exists separate to HTML DOM.

Comment: There's a lot of DOM that's common and some that's SVG specific and some that's HTML specific. jquery always choses the HTML version so you may run into trouble with things like the class attribute that work differently in SVG and HTML.